# Why does substracting characters gives wrong answer

Tags: javascript, string, character

If they concatenate

shouldn't be like:

a = "3"+"8"= "38"

b= "38"-"8"="3"

a="38"-"3"="8"

?

I also didn't understand why that solution doesn't work

where did the "0" come from ?

Comment: The `-` operator does not work the same way as `+`

Comment: "_where did the "0" come from_" `'3' + '8' === '38'` -> `'38' - '8' === 30`.

Answer (score 1):

Operator - converts values to numbers and returns NaN if its not convertable

Answer (score 0):

Substraction automatically converts to a number, where possible, before doing the operation.